# Needle search in array returns 0 if not found

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm using this function to search the (highest) array key when a value of userid is found:

```
function array_search_value($needle,$haystack) {
foreach($haystack as $key => $value) {
    if(in_array($needle, $value)) return $key;
}
  }
```

My array looks like this (it's generated by a simple query):

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [userid] => 1
        [1] => 2
        [score1] => 2
        [2] => 0
        [score2] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3
        [userid] => 3
        [1] => 2
        [score1] => 2
        [2] => 2
        [score2] => 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 4
        [userid] => 4
        [1] => 1
        [score1] => 1
        [2] => 1
        [score2] => 1
    )

[3] => 
)
```

This code:

```
echo array_search_value(4, $r)
```

Returns 2, which is correct.

Looking for 1 gives 0, which is correct.

However, when I search for 2 (which can't be found), it returns 0.
This, off course, is not correct... What I want it to do is return nothing at all, not 0.
I've tried tweeking the function by adding "== true" but that won't work either.

Anyone know's how to fix this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I search for 2 (which can't be found), it returns 0. This, off course, is not correct...

Looking at your provided array, it *is* correct. The value `2` appears in key `0`:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [userid] => 1
        [1] => 2 // here
        [score1] => 2 // and here
        [2] => 0
        [score2] => 0
    )
```

If you only want to look at the `userid` key, then you can't just use `in_array()`, but have to do such:

```
<?php
function array_search_value($needle,$haystack) {
foreach($haystack as $key => $value) {
    if($value['userid'] === $needle) return $key;
}
return null; // not found
  }

if (array_search_value(2, $r) === null) { /* doesn't happen */ }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to do! Thanks a lot! (info: had to change the "===" to "==" to make it work)

Answer (score 1):

When you search for `2` you will get `0` since you have `$haystack[0][score1] = 2`. You need to specify that you're looking for `userid` and not anything else.

```
foreach($haystack as $key => $value) {
  if ($value['userid'] == $needle) {
    return $key;
  }
}
```